# Remove values which are surrounded by a certain number of NAs

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data

I wish to remove values in a time series which are surrounded by blocks of `NA` of a certain minimal length.

Some toy data:

```
x = seq(0,10,length.out = 100)
y = sin(x) + rnorm(length(x), mean=0, sd=0.1)
y[20:21] = rep(NA, 2)
y[50:54] = rep(NA, 5)
y[55:59] = seq(-0.1, -0.8, length.out = 5)
y[60:64] = rep(NA, 5)
y[90:91] = rep(NA, 2)

df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

I wish to remove any sequence of y values which is less than 10 in length and which is preceeded and followed by 5 or more `NA` values.

In my toy data, the y values at index 55-59 has (a) less than 10 consecutive values, and have (b) 5 `NA` on *both* sides. Thus, this block of values should be removed.

The other values consists of longer blocks of values and/or are surrounded by short runs of `NA` (< 5) and should be kept.

Plot with the values to be removed in red color:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = df[55:59, ], color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: @MamounBenghezal Could you elaborate?

Comment: "Long real values" is hard for us to operationalize. It would be good if you could give us hard criteria for what to remove, e.g., "any data sequence less that 10 entries long and sandwiched between `NA`s". Perhaps edit your question to give a somewhat more complicated example and the output you expect.

Comment: Did my current edits clarify the problem or do you believe a further clarification is needed? (I'm still learning how to pose a question here).

Comment: That is something we should be able to work with. Of course, this question is a bit more intricate than the original one ;-) I'll try to find the time to edit my answer later today.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I'll try to make sure I ask it better the first time next time. Abstracting a problem to its key components is difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we will define the two thresholds you specified. (I set the second one to 4 so we can work consistently with "<" and ">", instead of the error-prone "<" and ">=").

```
threshold.data <- 10
threshold.NA <- 4
```

Now, the key is to work with *run length encoding* on `is.na(y)`. Look at `?rle`.

```
foo <- rle(is.na(y))
foo
```

First, we extract possible "candidate runs of NAs" by checking where the original data are `NA` (thus `foo$values` will be `TRUE`) *and* we have the specified minimum run length of `NA`s:

```
candidate.runs.NA <- which(foo$values & foo$lengths>threshold.NA)
```

We only want to proceed if we have at least two `NA` runs over the threshold:

```
if ( diff(range(candidate.runs.NA)) >= 2 ) {
```

Our goal is to find the indices of the non-`NA` data that we want to remove. For this, we find "candidate runs of (non-`NA`) data". In a first step, that includes all runs between the first and the last `NA` run identified above:

```
    candidate.runs.data <- seq(candidate.runs.NA[1]+1,tail(candidate.runs.NA,1)-1)
```

We refine this by two criteria. On the one hand, we only want sequences of non-`NA`s, and on the other hand, these sequences should be below the threshold in length:

```
    candidate.runs.data <- candidate.runs.data[!foo$values[candidate.runs.data] &
      foo$lengths[candidate.runs.data]<threshold.data]
```

In your example, `candidate.runs.data` will now have only one entry 5. This means that we need to remove all data in the 5th run of our `is.na` sequence. For this, we need to restore the actual indices:

```
    indices.to.remove <- as.vector(sapply(candidate.runs.data,function(kk)
      seq(sum(foo$lengths[1:(kk-1)])+1,sum(foo$lengths[1:kk]))))
```

This is a bit complicated, since I wrapped it in an `sapply()` call, in case we get *multiple*  `candidate.runs.data` to remove. Finally, we remove these data:

```
    y[indices.to.remove] <- NA
}
plot(x,y,"l")
```

[image]

Now, this seems to do what you want for your specific example. You may want to think about what you want to happen in boundary cases. For instance, this assumes that your series starts with a non-`NA`. And what should happen if you don't have *two* runs of five or more `NA`s, but *three*, or *five*? With or without shorter `NA` runs between the "long" runs? This script will consider any run of up to nine non-`NA`s between the first and the last "long" run as fair game.

Comment: It appears I will have to edit the question, your answer works but it isn't exactly what I had in mind. There can be multiple islands like this in a time-series and multiple NA values. I guess I should have been more explicit, my bad. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Took a bit of effort to pull it apart, but that's just a downright beautiful solution to this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can treat your time series as a character string and use advantages of regular expressions here. It's easy to solve the problem with the help of function `str_locate_all` from `stringr` package.

```
st <- paste0(as.integer(is.na(df$y)), collapse = '')
# [1] "0000000000000000000110000000000000000000000000000111110000011111000000000000000000000000011000000000"
require("stringr")
str_locate_all(st, "1{5,}0{,10}1{5,}") 
# pattern of at least 5 ones, then not more than 10 zeros, then again not less than 5 ones

# output will be:
# [[1]]
#      start end
# [1,]    50  64
```

Comment: This is also quite clever, and it's an excellent example of lateral thinking.

Comment: Thanks) I've had to work with regular expressions recently, so my mind was working in this direction)

Answer (score 2):

Another `rle` possibility:

Run lengths of `NA`:

```
r <- rle(is.na(y))
```

`values` (sensu `rle`) of non-`NA` (`FALSE`) which should be removed from the data (runs shorter than 10, and preceeded and followed by runs of `NA` of more than 4) are replaced with `TRUE`:

```
r$values[!r$values & r$lengths < 10 &
           c(0, head(r$lengths, -1)) > 4 &
           c(tail(r$lengths, -1), 0) > 4] <- TRUE
```

The updated `rle` `values` are then used together with the `lengths` to generate a boolean index to replace relevant y values with `NA`:

```
y[rep(r$values, r$lengths)] <- NA
```

Using plotting code of OP:
[image]

Comment: That's even simpler. Also thank you for editing the original question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: No problem! I thought your question was interesting and I hoped it could reach a wider audience with some editing.

Answer (score 0):

complete.cases() would be nice for you?
This function makes all rows with NA to dissapear..
Maybe is too much drastic for you...

Comment: I'm not trying to make the NAs disappear, I'm trying to make the data sandwiched between the NAs disappear. Think of it this way, a sensor fails, they try to bring it back up for a few days but it still is producing outlying data, and then they take it down again until they fix it. It's the outlying data in between I am trying to remove.